# pip install distarray --> mpi.h not found, cannot install mpi4py

Tags: visual-studio-2010, python-3.4

I have tried to install distarray which requires a C++ compiler (which I got from MS) and mpi4py. The installer cannot locate mpi.h and I cannot even install mpi4py by itself. The documentation says I should set an ENV-path, but which path, to Visual studio?

---

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo
 /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tc_confi
gtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
    _configtest.c
    _configtest.c(2) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpi.h': No
such file or directory
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj
    failure.
    error: Cannot find 'mpi.h' header. Check your configuration!!!
```

---

What am I doing wrong? I have tried both in a Windows and a Linux environment without luck. As admin and sudo.

(Should there be tags for mpi4py, mpi.h, mpi.cfg as I cannot create these as a new user)

Comment: You should use MPI compiler wrappers. See [this][1]. hope helps you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920083/fatal-error-mpi-h-no-such-file-or-directory-include-mpi-h

Comment: how do I use the wrapper? pip install wrapper package or do I call the wrapper separately?